# Sumar la fecha de un Date picker más la cantidad de días que se seleccinan de un select2. Y mostar el resultado de la suma en otro Date Picker

Tags: php, javascript, html5, datepicker, select2

Tengo 2 `Date picker` y un `select2`. El primer `Date picker` tiene la fecha inicial. El `select2` contiene X cantidad días que se sumaran con la fecha inicial.El segundo `Date picker` es la fecha final donde se mostrará el resultado de la suma de la fecha inicial + el numero que se haya seleccionado del `select2`.

Estoy usando `javascript` y `php`

Alguien que me ayude a generar la función por favor.

Esta es mi función `js` con la que intento dar solución, donde: **dt_fecha_nacimiento** es la fecha inicial **cmb_dias** es la cantidad de días a sumar y **dt_fecha_siguiente_etapa** es donde se mostrara el resultado de la suma.

```
$( function() {
    $("#dt_fecha_nacimineto").datepicker();
    $("#dt_fecha_siguiente_etapa").datepicker();
    $("#cmb_dias").val();

    $("#dt_fecha_nacimineto").on("change", function() {
        
        var fecha2 = $("#cmb_dias").val();
        var fecha = $("#dt_fecha_nacimineto").datepicker("getDate");
        fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate() + fecha2); 

        $("#dt_fecha_siguiente_etapa").datepicker("setDate", fecha);
    });
  });
```

[image: acá una ilustración de lo que quiero lograr]

Comment: Kevin, agrega algo de código para que sea más fácil ayudarte. Si no lo has hecho, haz el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que te familiarices con las reglas de la comunidad.

Comment: Listo DjCrazy, ya he incluido el código que estoy implementado para intentar realizar la suma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para calcular fechas sumando un número determinado de días, te puedes apoyar en la librería `moment.js`, la cual te permite operar con fechas a tu necesidad.

Hice algunas modificaciones a la estructura de tu código, debes adaptar el código del ejemplo a tu proyecto.

Lo primero que debes hacer es importar la librería o agregar la dependencia:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

El siguiente paso es construir el código en `js` para realizar el cálculo. En el ejemplo dejé comentarios para que sea más fácil entender lo que hago.

```js
//Al hacer click en el botón... (Debes cambiar esta acción en tu proyecto)
$("#calcular").on("click", function() {
  //Obtener la fecha de nacimiento
  let fecha = $("#dt_fecha_nacimiento").val();
  //Obtener la cantidad de días
  let dias = $("#cmb_dias").val();
  //Calcular la sumatoria
  let fecha2 = moment(fecha).add(dias, 'days').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
  //Asignar la nueva fecha al input siguiente etapa
  $("#dt_fecha_siguiente_etapa").val(fecha2);
});
```

```html
<label for="dt_fecha_nacimiento">Fecha nacimiento: </label>
<input type="date" id="dt_fecha_nacimiento"><br>
<label for="cmb_dias">Días siguiente etapa: </label>
<input type="number" id="cmb_dias"><br>
<label for="dt_fecha_siguiente_etapa">Fecha siguiente etapa: </label>
<input type="text" id="dt_fecha_siguiente_etapa"><br>
<button id="calcular">Calcular</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Explicando la línea en la que interviene `moment.js`:

```
moment(fecha).add(dias, 'days').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```

- En `moment(fecha)` le pasamos por parámetro el valor del campo **dt_fecha_nacimiento**.
- En `add(dias, 'days')` le pasamos en el primer parámetro el valor del campo **cmb_dias**, el segundo parámetro es propio de la librería e indica que se van a agregar la cantidad de días del primer parámetro.
- `format('DD/MM/YYYY')` se encarga de darle el formato que elijas a la fecha de salida.

Te dejo un enlace a la documentación oficial de la librería para que la conozcas a fondo, si así lo deseas... https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: Fabuloso, muchas gracias. me a funcionado a la perfección. Le agradezco mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Me alegra que te hay servido.